# Whitelist specific input device types

Tags: java, android, input-devices

I need a way to check a KeyEvent to see what type it is. I want to exclude everything except a device's (SmartPhone/Tables) own hardware/capacitive buttons. No mouse, no BT keyboards or game pads etc. I only want to interact with it's own buttons. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the getDeviceId() from KeyEvent. If it comes back 0 it's supposed to be the device itself.

I don't know how reliable that is, though.

Comment: The hardware keys gives med 8 as id and the capacitive gives me 10. An that is properly just the ID's of this particular device and installation.